# Trig AlertDailog whe check the checkbox

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-alertdialog

I want to set that when I check checkbox then show the `AlertDialog`.
but there is a problem happen..
the Eclipse always show a red line under my `AlertDialog`.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(setting.this)
```

code:

```
private CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener chkPasswordListener = new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (chkSetPassword.isChecked()){
                new AlertDialog.Builder(setting.this)  //AlertDialog show red line.
                .setMessage("Message,確定要結束?")
                .setPositiveButton("確定", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {                   
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i)
            //      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i)  
            //      TODO Auto-generated method stub                 
                    {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("取消", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i)
                    {
            //      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //      TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                })
                .show();
            }
        }
```

is there something I lost?
Please help me..

Comment: Could you gimme the import statement of CheckBox, please? It is not related to the problem, just I am curious.

Comment: Can you move the mouse cursor over the red line and let us know , what the error it shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should finish your code the following way:

```
            }

        })
        .show();
    }
  };      // THIS LINE WAS MISSING
}
```

You should close with the }; this line:

```
 private CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener chkPasswordListener
     = new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
```

Comment: Thank you for your support..but, it's still happen..
I capture the pic in [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pliyh4qyclu4hnk/Tay_6HkOq5)

Comment: Finish with: } } }; } instead of } }; } }

Comment: thank you. I replace that you tell me, but the error is still there .[link]https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pliyh4qyclu4hnk/Tay_6HkOq5

Comment: Now the ; seems to be at the right place. This is another error. What message shows Eclipse if you put the cursor over AlertDialog?

Comment: Does AlertDialog have an import statement?

Comment: no, it's still same..but some import which don't be needed is gone.

Comment: I fix the problem, it didn't add "import android.app.AlertDialog" automatically....Thank you all for all support..